# Wordpress - Search also in custom post meta

Tags: wordpress

I have some custom post meta attached to posts (fields : "question", "answer"), how it's possible to search in them also ? I have tested this function, but doesn't work:

http://codingsomething.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/custom-post-meta-in-wordpress-search/

Thanks

Comment: how did you implemented above code? did you changed __meta_key__ to your meta keys?

Comment: yes I did, but doesn't work

Comment: can I have url please? you have to set multiple meta keys. with or condition.